# Run app for a long time in background

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5, background-process

I have googled an serached a lot here about background runnin aps but have no idea. My app sends to my server synchronous(mean, scheduled) GETs and receives a response. The response is a dictionary of arrays. I want my app to run all the time and send that GET, but Apple restrics this for just Audi, GPS-location, Vo-IP.. Some of the comments say "use an empty CGLocationManager loop or play an empty voice" but i have no idea how to do. Can anyone please help?

**EDIT:** The app will run on just my own devices, so it isn't problem if Apple doesn't let me sell it

Comment: Your workarounds will probably not work, Apple will not allow apps that attempt them.

Comment: it will run just on my device, i wont sell it on the store

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could register for Audio services background mode and play a silent music track on repeat. That will keep your app alive in the background.

Comment: One more question: If, on device, i play a new audio file will not the app crash(since it will rey to play two audios)?

Comment: probably. But that's why Apple doesn't allow spurious apps to run in the background. You could also try registering for location updates instead. The idea is the same: Run your app in a mode that keeps it alive in the background even if it doesn't actually use that mode. Alternatively, Try setting local notifications to fire and wake up your app at regular intervals. It will bring you app to the front each time, though. But as you said; this is for yourself, not the store, so you are free to try barbaric solutions. Alternatively - try a different solution for keeping your app updated.

Comment: can you give a example about Audio services background mode and play a silent music track on repeat

Comment: i  do not know how to check if my app is killed?